# Counterexample or proof: Integral convergence wrt to some measure

Tags: integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Is it true that $\left(u_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$ with $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}u_n = u \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$ and $\int u_n d \mu \rightarrow 0$ implies $\int u d\mu = 0$ where $\mu$ is an arbitrary measure.

If so, how do I prove this? If not, what is a counter example? My own intution tells me that this would not be satisfied in general due to the dominated convergence theorem ($u_n$ is not uniformly bounded) but I fail to find a counter example.

Comment: In what sense does the convergence $u_n \to u$ hold? In $L_1(\mu)$?

Comment: Sorry. The sequence converges pointwise to u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preposition of the dominated convergence theorem guides us in finding a counterexample, as you wrote correctly.

Consider $[0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure $\mu$. Then the functions $u_n := 1- n\chi_{(0, \frac 1n)}$, are integrable with 
$$ \int_0^1 u_n\, d\mu = 1 - n \cdot \frac 1n = 0 $$
hence $u_n \in L^1(\mu)$ and $\int_0^1 u_n \, d\mu \to 0$. The functions converge pointwise to $1 =: u \in L^1(\mu)$, and 
$$ \int_0^1 u\, d\mu = 1 \ne 0 $$